# Emulating a resistive keypad

Tags: transistors, digital-potentiometer, raspberry-pi-pico

I am building a circuit to emulate a resistive keypad. Each digit has a specific resistance between 3k ohms and 30k ohms. When there is no digit pressed the circuit is open. When a digit is pressed the circuit is closed.

I am using a DS1804-50 and a Raspberry Pi Pico to simulate the various digits and their respective resistances, then I use a 5v relay (also controlled by the Pico) to close the circuit at the selected resistance for ~100ms to simulate the key press.

This is working well but I would like to get rid of the mechanical relay, I could maybe use a solid state relay but it feels like there should be a better / cheaper option.

I'm an electronics novice. What would be the best way to "close" the circuit briefly once I've set the resistance on the DS1804? Maybe some kind of transistor in place of the relay?

I've tried to design a circuit to illustrate. The Pico sets the resistance on the DS1804 and then briefly closes and opens the relay to simulate the keypress. I would like to get rid of the mechanical relay.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to show your circuit.

Comment: Array of 6 mosfets and resistors with values of 32k 16k 8k 4k 2k 1k should do the job since you can emulate any 1k step with them.

Comment: Also the emitter and collector pins on the relay are swapped out in the schematic.

Comment: The transistor to trigger the relay is connected wrong in your circuit. As for your `What would be the best way to "close" the circuit briefly once I've set the resistance on the DS1804?` question, I'd like to suggest "analog SPDT" ICs. Check voltage/current requirements and you can find a suitable one.

Comment: I apologise for the error on the schematic. The circuit is working though, I was just looking for an alternative to the relay. Thank you for the suggestions. I've never used a mosfet nor had I heard of "analog SPDT" ICs before. It is 9v / 1mA.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an analog mux.

It allows you to have several resistors and connect any one of them between the two pins, so you don't need an adjustable digital pot.

If you don't want an analog mux, use an analog switch which is a bit simpler.